# Float vs Integer MAX_VALUE

Tags: java, primitive-types

`int` and `float` has 4 bytes for value.

If there is such a float value like `0.5` that int doesn't contain, is there any value that `int` contains, but `float`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're looking for numbers that can be presented with an `int`, but not `float`.

One of them is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

```
int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
float f = i;      // or 2147483647f
System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(String.format("%f", f));
```

Displays

```
2147483647
2147483648.000000
```

This is because while both have `32-bits` a `float` divides the bits to be used for the sign (`1 bit`), the exponent (`8 bits`) and the significand or mantissa (`23 bits`).

Comment: But why it shows `2147483648.000000` it's `2^31` more then float can hold, right?

Comment: A `float` can hold much larger values than `int` due to its exponent. Try printing the value of `Float.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ A float can hold a much *larger* value than a `32-bit int`, but it has less *accuracy* (at least when measuring with integer numbers, as seen in my post).